# Cypher query - creation of graph from csv file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two csv files:
(clean_data_2.csv : Sample Content as under)

[image]

(stationdata.csv : Sample Content as under)

[image]

From my cypher query, I want that each station is represented as node and relationship is represented as count.

I did something like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///stationdata.csv" AS line
CREATE (s:station{id:line.station_id,station_name:line.name});
```

Loading all station data: it creates all the nodes - source and destination columns

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///clean_data_2.csv" AS line
MATCH (src:station),(dst:station)
CREATE (src)-[:TO{ count: [line.count]}]->(dst);
```

The above part runs, but does not give me count in the relationship between nodes.

I am new to Neo4j - graph databases, thanks!

Comment: Can you show in your question the *actual contents* of the 2 CSV files?

Comment: Hi @cybersam: I have added snippets :)

Comment: That is a bit better, but can you show snippets of the **raw data** -- not whatever is displayed by a tool (like a spreadsheet app)? Also, please delete the original tabular data, as that is incorrect.

Comment: Also, one glaring issue is that your second query's `MATCH` clause does not specify the `name`s of the `station` nodes for `src` and `dst`, so all possible pairs of `station` nodes will be matched. That *should* cause the creation of a lot of extra `TO` relationships with `count` properties, and yet you seem to be saying that you don't get any `count` properties?

Comment: @cybersam: Yeah, exactly! I am getting extra relationships, and I am not able to figure it out, how to specifiy names for src and dst nodes.

Apologies, my question was not clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query's `MATCH` clause does not specify the names of the station nodes for `src` and `dst`, so all possible pairs of station nodes would be matched. That would cause the creation of a lot of extra `TO` relationships with `count` properties.

Try using this instead of your second query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///clean_data_2.csv" AS line
MATCH (src:station {name: line.src}), (dst:station {name: line.dst})
CREATE (src)-[:TO {count: TOINTEGER(line.count)}]->(dst);
```

This query specifies the station names in the `MATCH` clause, which your query was not doing.

This query also converts the `line.count` value from a string (which all values produced by `LOAD CSV` are) into an integer, and assigns it as a scalar value to the `count` property, as there does not seem a need for it to be an array.